# Configure multiple switch values in Nuke

Tags: configuration, nuke

My comp has multiple switch nodes, which works as a configurator. Is there a way I can set these configurations at once, rather than going through each switch node and selecting the values?

**Example**
Set the following switch values and store as 'Configuration A'.

```
switch a = 0
switch b = 1
switch c = 3
switch d = 2
switch e = 7
```

Then another set of values for Configuration B, C, D...etc?
I can then select the configurations more efficiently.

[image: This is my current setup]

My current setup, I've just created a NoOp and added the following expression to the switches:

[value int (TRIM_SELECT.leathers)]

Which is basically the switch node with a label, but still have to configure these for each option.

Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @user2538833! How your properties of `Switch1` node must look like? Publish a print-screen, please.

Comment: There are many ways to achieve what you are looking for. Are you looking for a way to do it live with expressions, or by running a python script? Do you have a set format for storing configurations or is it all up in the air at this point?